# Why am I getting NaN when trying to display average from two state values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

Newbie here. Trying to learn React and I am currently trying to display the `average=(good+bad)/all`
However, I keep getting `NaN` which I am assuming I am getting because my state values are all 0. I am confused as to why this is because after calling `setClicks(newStats)` I thought the stats are updated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"


const App = () =>{
  const [stats,setClicks] = useState({good:0,neutral:0,bad:0,all:0,positive:0,average:0})

  const handleGood=()=>
  {
    const newStats={
    ...stats,
    all: stats.all +1,
    good:stats.good +1,
    average: (stats.good - stats.bad)/stats.all,
    }
    setClicks(newStats)
    console.log("Stats.good",stats.good)
    console.log("Stats.bad",newStats.bad)
    console.log("Stats.all",stats.all)
  }

  const handleBad=()=>
  {
    const newStats= {
      ...stats,
      bad: stats.bad+1,
      all: stats.all+1,
      average: (stats.good - stats.bad)/stats.all,
    }
    setClicks(newStats)
  }

  const handleNeutral =() =>
  {
    const newStats={
      ...stats,
      neutral:stats.neutral +1,
      all: stats.all+1,
      average: (stats.good - stats.bad)/stats.all,
    }
    setClicks(newStats)
  }

  
  
  const Button =({handleClick,text})=>{
    return(
    <button onClick={handleClick}>{text}</button> )
  }
  
  
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Give Feedback</h1>
      <Button handleClick={handleGood} text="good"/>
      <Button handleClick={handleNeutral} text="neutral"/>
      <Button handleClick={handleBad} text="bad"/>
      <br/>
      <h2>Statistics</h2>
      <p>good: {stats.good}</p>
      <p>neutral: {stats.neutral}</p>
      <p>bad: {stats.bad}</p>
      <p>all:{stats.all}</p>
      <p>average: {stats.average}</p>
      <p>positive: {stats.positive}</p>

    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[Image for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP9L0.png)

What is the best way to change state? How should this be done so `NaN` does not appear?

Comment: Your initial values are all zeros, your first calculation is 0/0 whish valuated to NaN, its not related to React.

Comment: You want to get the average but your calculation is `(good - bad) / all`. That is not the way on how to get the average in Math dude. Its something like this `sumOfAllGood / totalCountOfGood`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the initial calculation of average, you need to use the updated values:

```
const handleGood= () => {
  const newAll = stats.all + 1;
  const newGood = stats.good + 1;
    const newStats={
      ...stats,
      all: newAll ,
      good:newGood ,
      average: (newGood - stats.bad)/newAll,
    }
    setClicks(newStats);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NaN because you are dividing 0/0 and not calculating the average correctly. You should use new good, bad, ... values for average.

In this part of your code:

```
const newStats={
    ...stats,
    all: stats.all +1,
    good:stats.good +1,
    average: (stats.good - stats.bad)/stats.all,
    }
```

You are calculating average with the old values of all, good in your state.

By the way, adding Math.abs avoid getting a negative average value.

This is an updated version of your handleGood function.

```
const handleGood=()=>
  {
    const newAll = stats.all +1;
    const newGood = stats.good +1;
    const newAverage = Math.abs(newGood-stats.bad)/newGood
    const newStats={
    ...stats,
    all: newAll,
    good:newGood,
    average: newAverage,
    }
    setClicks(newStats)
    console.log("Stats.good",newStats.good)
    console.log("Stats.bad",newStats.bad)
    console.log("Stats.all",newStats.all)
  }
```